# Remove duplicates in Join statement in mysql and group

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables

**table1**

```
Name    marks
John    50
Smith   70
Adam    60
Roy     70
```

**table2**

```
Score   Grade   other
50       C       1.5
60       B       0.7
70       A       0.8
70       A       1.0
```

I want to get how many people have got A, B, C passes
I want to get an output as

```
Grade Count
C      1
B      1
A      2
```

Query I tried was

```
SELECT  table2.Grade, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT table2.Grade) as count
FROM    table1
LEFT JOIN table2
        ON table1.Mark = table2.Score
GROUP BY table2.Grade;
```

But it Gives

```
Grade Count
C      1
B      1
A      4
```

So How to remove the duplicates ?
Please help.

Comment: For what reason you are joining the table2 with table1?

Comment: to get the relevant grade to marks he obtained

Comment: why are there two entries for `A` anyway?

Comment: that's is question it has two entries. these tables are not the actual tables i am working on these are simple example tables so it is easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your second table, you got duplicate rows:

```
Score   Grade   other
50       C       1.5
60       B       0.7
70       A       0.8
70       A       1.0
```

Here, there are to A's, and when you joing with first table according to the field "Grade--Score", the whole join is:

```
Jhon 50 C
Smith 70 A
Smith 70 A --> Second A from second table
Adam  60 B
Roy   70 A
Roy   70 A --> Second A from second table
```

So group by and count will result 4 for the field grade here:

```
A  4 --> 2 Smith and 2 Roy
B  1
C  1
```

**So**, to get how many single person per grade:

```
select tb2.Grade GradeMark, count(*) TotalPersons
from table1 as tb1
left join (select tbi2.Score, distinct(tbi2.Grade), tbi2.other,  from table2 tbi2) as tb2 on tb2.Grade = tb1.marks
group by tb2.Grade
```

This query will select distinct values from table2, join with table one and count the results per grade so you should get:

```
A  2
B  1
C  1
```

Comment: That is the question lets assume there is some other parameter in that table2.

Comment: You say "I want to get how many people have got A, B, C passes I want to get an output as" So here, total is 4 for A, what is your real question here?

Comment: Only smith and Roy have got A s so its 2.

Comment: Please check-out my update, you can join two table after "distinctly" selecting second table per grade letter, the distinct selection part is this: `"(select tbi2.Score, distinct(tbi2.Grade), tbi2.other,  from table2 tbi2)"`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `JOIN` for this. You can try like below using a simple `group by` and get the `count()`

```
select Grade, count(*) as `Count`
from table2
group by Grade;
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. i want to get how many people have got A, B, C passes I've edited the question sorry for inconvenience .

Comment: you want like how many people got grade then  `select name,grade,count(*) as total from b1 inner join b2 on marks = score group by name;`